# Eclipse format code: force array initializer to be on same line

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

When I format my code in Eclipse, my array initializer goes from:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
```

to:

```
int[] array =     
{1, 2, 3};
```

Why is the `{1, 2, 3};` on a new line instead of the same line as the array declaration after formatting?

How do I fix this so that the `{1, 2, 3}` stays on the same line as the `int[]` array after formatting?

Would you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Formatter > Edit active profile > Braces and change Array initializer from "Next line" to "Same line"

Comment: Thank you so much, I just learned this as well from:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRAeKO-5xpQ  Thank you for answering my question and helping me.